# mongodb - Dump restore throws error

Tags: mongodb

I'm getting this below error while restoring dump into mongodb,

```
Mon Jul 27 14:08:52.936         going into namespace [test.BC_2022_tmp]
Mon Jul 27 14:08:52.936 warning: Restoring to viacrm.BC_2022_tmp without dropping. Restored data will be inserted without raising errors; check your server log
Mon Jul 27 14:08:52.937 file /home/dev/test/BC_2022_tmp.bson empty, skipping
Mon Jul 27 14:08:52.937         Creating index: { key: { _id: 1 }, ns: "viacrm.BC_2022_tmp", name: "_id_" }
Mon Jul 27 14:08:52.938 ERROR: Error creating index test.BC_2022_tmp: 13347 err: "local.oplog.rs missing. did you drop it? if so restart server"
Abandon (core dumped)
```

**Dump Restore command:**

```
mongorestore -d test /home/dev/crm
```

Please can anyone help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Did you drop the database before restoring?

Comment: yes .................